# How to save elements of a nested list in Python using a loop and deleting the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I am trying to create a list of lists (nested list) taking the number of element and no of lists from users as b, a respectively. However, how can I save the temp_list into list_of_lists. Since I am deleting temp_list after appending it to list_of_list, elements from the later list are also being deleted.

```
a, b= map(int,input().split())
i = 0
list_of_lists = []
while i < b:
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(map(float, input().split()))
    print(temp_list, i)
    list_of_list.append(temp_list)
    del temp_list[:]
    i += 1

print(list_of_lists)
```

Comment: There is no particular *reason* to delete the elements as you add them to your new list. Suppose you have `li=[item1, item2, item3]` and you take each item and add to a new list. Likely (depending on the characteristics of each item) the new list comprises a pointer to those items -- not a copy. If your items are strings or ints (both immutable in Python) the new list is *definitely* a pointer to those elements; not a copy. Therefore you are making this process a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @dawg Thank you for the explanation. However, what happens to the elements in this case. Since new temp_list is created everytime, what happens to the elements from the earlier iteration:                                                                                                                  a, b = map(int, input().split())
list_of_lists = []
for i in range(b):
    temp_list = list(map(float, input().split()))
    print(temp_list, i)
    list_of_lists.append(temp_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:

- You shouldn't `del temp_list[:]` you are deleting the object you just added.
- Your loop would be better as a `for` loop.
- Your variable is called `list_of_lists` not `list_of_list`, so `list_of_list.append()` should throw a `NameError`
- `map` in Py3 returns an iterator, so you need to turn it into a list, you could use `temp_list.extend(map(...))` but you can just create it directly. Note: your first use of `map(...)` is unpacked into individual variables so works as expected.

Updated code:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
list_of_lists = []
for i in range(b):
    temp_list = list(map(float, input().split()))
    print(temp_list, i)
    list_of_lists.append(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are deleting the temp list each time

```
del temp_list[:]
```

instead of

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

you can simply use it like

```
a, b = map(int, input())
```

and enter the input like 3,4 python will automatically get it as a tuple and will assign it to variable a,b respectively

```
a, b = map(int, input()) #3,4
list_of_lists = []
for i in range(b):
    temp_list = list(map(float, input())) 
    print(temp_list, i)
    list_of_lists.append(temp_list)
print (list_of_lists)
```

Comment: Your description of `map` and `input` applies to Python 2, not Python 3 (which the OP is asking about).

Comment: `a, b = map(int, input())` doesn't do what you are expecting it to do, an input of `3,4` would through a `ValueError` on the `,`. `ast.literal_eval(input())` would work as you describe.

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable information . It will definitely hepl me. Thanks